# Change scatterplot labels in ELKI result visualization

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, elki

Is it possible to easily change the scatterplot labels in the ELKI result visualization, maybe using parameters?

The default axes are labeled Column 0 and Column 1 for 2-dimensional data. It would be nice to change this to Latitude and Longitude for my case. I'm running DBSCAN with ELKI version 0.6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no parameter for this. ELKI already has way too many parameters, doesn't it?

But (I believe there is a bug in 0.6.5 there, you may need to build the current git version yourself) if there is a *column label* available, ELKI will use the column label instead of enumerating axes. If the first row of a file does not contain numbers, the default parser will interpret is as column labels.

This is a visualization of clustering 1 day of coordinates in the 1% Twitter sample with HDBSCAN*:

[image]

Or you just export the graph to SVG and use a SVG editor and change the label as desired. I recommend **Inkscape**. The ability to fine-tune graphics with Inkscape was the key reason why we chose to use SVG.